# Wrong page for subdomain url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a website that runs in the root of the webserver "www" folder. There I have a .htaccess file like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1
RewriteRule ^rochii-de-seara/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/rochie/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ colectie.php?colectie=$1&rochie=$2
RewriteRule ^rochii-de-seara/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ colectie.php?colectie=$1
RewriteRule ^rochii-de-seara/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ colectie.php?colectie=$1&subpage=$2


RewriteRule ^material-rochie/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ colectie.php?material=$1
RewriteRule ^culoare-rochie/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ colectie.php?culoare=$1
RewriteRule ^tip-rochie/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ colectie.php?tip=$1

RewriteRule ^colectie/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/rochie/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ colectie.php?colectie=$1&rochie=$2?nume=$3?comentariu=$4?rochie=$5?ref=$6?submit=$7
```

The website itself works very well at the moment, but ...

I've created a subdomain called "rochii-seara" (mapped to the **"rochiideseara"** subfolder in the root and there are no redirects) and I want to access it from the following url: **"rochii-seara.domain.com"**. The problem is that when I try to access the subdomain, I am redirected to the homepage of the website. If I access it through **"domain.com/rochiideseara"** it works fine. I'm not an expert on Apache, but I guess there's a problem with the .htaccess file in the root. Can you please help?

Thanks in advance!

LE: The .htaccess file in the **"rochiideseara"** subfolder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/rochiideseara/.htaccess` have this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

to override all rules of parent .htaccess

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work! I'm being redirected to the homepage ... btw, the subdomain has a Wordpress installation.

Comment: **subdomain has a Wordpress** wow! why did you not put this in question?

Comment: If subdomain has a Wordpress then it must be having default WP .htaccess also? Where is that?

Comment: In the .htaccess file in the "rochiideseara" (WP installation) subfolder I've added "RewriteEngine On" as recommended and it was empty from the beginning. The WP installation was done through Cpanel console.

Comment: Not sure how WP is working without default htaccess, also WP needs site and home URL to be `seara.domain.com` in permalinks.

Comment: I beats me ... I've set in the `wp_options` table the value "http://rochii-seara.domain.com" for both `home` and `siteurl` option_value fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71352/discussion-between-valicu2000-and-anubhava).